# When any record has certain attribute, change parent status

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, activerecord

I want to change the `status` of a `Job`-record, **after** the `status` of any of its children (`Jobdetails`) is set to true.

Basically the code should be something like:

```
if every Job.jobdetail.status == true
  Job.status = true
end
```

the problem is, that i dont know how to check for any. Of course i know the `where`-statement in rails but I am not sure how to express the "any" without an each iteration, which wont work in this case i guess. Everytime after I update the `Jobdetails`, I want to check if the other `Jobdetails` are "done" too. Imagine the function like a progressbar. If every sub-job is done, change the status of the main-job to done. How do I achieve this?

thanks in regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `my_job` be marked as *done* only when all `jobdetails` are done, then you just need to check if at least one `jobdetail` has `status = false`:

```rb
my_job.status = true unless my_job.jobdetails.find_by(status: false)
```

Comment: thank you. i didnt knew of the unless statement. can i place this snippet in my update action? since its an association im not sure if i can apply the code in my `jobdetails_controller`

Comment: Yes, you can, although it's better to put it in the model. Anyway, if you don't know how to do the later it's ok to use the controller until you get used to the Rails way.